# Battery Cycle Information

Tags: windows, laptop, battery, hardware-detection

I have a windows based laptop, I want to explore certain hardware based information, like battery cycles of the laptop. How do I get to these information ? Is there any way to access them ?

Answer (score 0):

**Generate battery report**

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and select Command Prompt (Admin).
2. Type the following command `powercfg /batteryreport` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: how do I make changes to this information ?